# How to mock relative requests in Vitest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vite, vitest

Vitest is currently failing because of an error that results from an endpoint not being available locally. Naturally I looked into how to mock endpoints and found this: https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#requests.

However, the fetch that is calling the endpoint is not calling it relatively like so `/oauth/token`. When running Vitest, this results in the error `TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported` because it uses `node-fetch` under the hood and [node-fetch can only handle absolute URLs](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/481).

```
export const restHandlers = [
  rest.get('/oauth/token', (_, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(token))),
];

const server = setupServer(...restHandlers);

beforeAll(() => server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: 'error' }));
afterAll(() => server.close());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
```

This is my code mocking the endpoint but it can not act because the call fails which produces an unhandled error which in turn fails the Vitest run - how can I solve this? I am fine with ignoring the unhandled error if mocking is not possible.

Comment: You may want to use new URL(relativeURL, baseURL) to resolve the URL before passing it to node-fetch.

Comment: @Nikos, I can't because in the code the base URL is not known. It depends on which site the code is running. I cannot adjust the code to be tested.

Comment: your mocks can modify the fetch, we usually do that with api's in unit tests

Comment: @Nikos how tho?

Comment: mock the nodefetch import with vitest

Comment: try vi.stubGlobal(... or https://dev.to/akirakashihara/how-to-mock-node-fetch-with-vitest-4jni

Comment: @Nikos how would that help? Node-fetch comes bundled with vitest and is never imported, mocking the import has no effect.

Comment: You could just don't use relative paths and use `window.location.origin` instead to always have absolute paths on your fetches, I used `msw` to mock requests and it's pretty simple to use.